# Quitar archivos de log en el comando wget de Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnu

estoy usando el comando `wget "www.url.com"` en un crontab para hacer una petición y traer una información, pero cada vez que se ejecuta me genera archivos de log que no necesito, probé con el parámetro -q pero no me funciona, gracias por su ayuda...

Comment: Prueba con `wget "www.url.com" > /dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: Curioso que los logs no los necesitas hasta que los necesitas, por lo regular cuando algo sale mal; logrotate te ayuda administrarlos.

Comment: @Sal O luego son puros warnings... igual está raro.

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza `-o /dev/null`

```
wget -q -o /dev/null blabla
```